# Rails: Associate posts with user and location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a `Post` model in my app, which `belongs_to`a `User` model, as well as a `Location` model. Both the `User` and `Location` models use the `has_many` relation with `Post`.

Now, in my `Post` controller's create action, I want to automatically associate the `Post` with the currently logged in user (available to me as `current_user` through Devise).

Also, it should associate with a pre-existing `Location` if one exists with the same `address` field (which he enters through the form), or create a new one and associate it with that if not.

My `Post` model has a `user_id` field as well a `location_id` field for this purpose.

How do I accomplish the two associations automatically in the create action when the user creates a new Post?

Comment: @Dogbert Updated. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: This is a question that can easily be answered by reading the documentation. Try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for starters. You are unlikely to get good answers because of this, as it looks like you haven't put in any effort to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use 2 statements.

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
@post.location_id = params[:location_id] # change this to whatever you're passing.
@post.save
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know setting the `location_id` field would automatically associate them together for me. Thank you.

Comment: If your Post model has an association with Location (Post has one location), it might be better to lookup the location first: @post.location = Location.find(params[:location_id)).