# Rails - Associate user to review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having difficulty associating a review to the current user. Here are my models:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

end
```

Review model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :venue
    belongs_to :user

end
```

Venue model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :reviews
    has_many :menu_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews

end
```

Review controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
    @review = @venue.reviews.create(review_params)

    if @review.save
      redirect_to venue_path(@venue)
    else

    end
  end

  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:title, :body, :rating)
  end

end
```

Just need a way to associate the review to the current user once the current user creates a new review for a venue.

I made the authentication from scratch following a tutorial from here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

I consulted the following before posting but couldn't figure it out:

[Rails: Associate posts with user and location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983244/rails-associate-posts-with-user-and-location)

[Associate user_id to the comment model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299798/associate-user-id-to-the-comment-model)

[Devise how to associate current user to post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009295/devise-how-to-associate-current-user-to-post)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're already associating Venue to Review `has_many :reviews`. Do the same thing in User. Then in the controller where you create the review do `@review.user = current_user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is to create a new `review` in two scopes at once: in `@venue.reviews` and `current_user.reviews`). **Oh hang on**, the latter is not even defined? Let's define that on `User` first:

```
has_many :reviews
```

Then instead of just `@venue.reviews` use a combination of two scopes:

```
  @venue.reviews.merge(current_user.reviews).create(review_params)
# ^----------------this one----------------^
```

...and the created objects will have properties of both, unless they're conflicting, in which case the latter scope will take precedence.